# Pandas export text column as a single, unescaped, text file

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to export the entire concatenation of a single dataframe column, to a file, for use as one big text blob, for a downstream unsupervised machine learning task. (give or take a separator character between the strings).

It looks like the pandas csv writer is not built for this special case, it insists on escaping characters, and it actually should.

```
df.to_csv('output.txt', columns = ['tokens'], header=False, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

> _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

This is very understandable, as the csv packages scope their methods for symmetry, and not escaping means a one way street.

How would you *efficiently* spit out the concatenation of a single dataframe column's values, given that the dataframe is at least one million rows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going to have issues with quoting as long as you're using a CSV writer to write raw text. Why not iterate and write to a text file directly?

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for text in df['tokens'].tolist():
        f.write(text + '\n')
```

Or, in a single line,

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df['tokens'].str.cat(sep='\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Given `tokens` is the dataframe column name:

```
from pathlib import Path

as_one_long_blurb = output.tokens.str.cat(sep='\n')
Path('tokens.txt').write_text(as_one_long_blurb)
```

I like this variant in that it can boil down to a single line of code aside the global import.

Comment: I like your idea but keep in mind that concatenation can become a challenge with long strings. You could also do `result = '\n'.join(df.tokens.tolist())` and write this to a file.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks! are you in fact saying that `str.cat` would be order of magnitude slower or memory hungry compared to `join` on `.tolist`?

Comment: I wouldn't say an order of magnitude slower, but str.join is faster since it runs at C speed without any overhead. Keep in mind they're both memory hungry O(n) compared to efficiently iterating over.